# What are all operating systems Supported by AEM 6.2?

Tags: aem

I just want to know What are the operating systems that is Supported by AEM 6.2

Answer (score 2):

The [Technical Requirements](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/technical-requirements.html) documentation lists down all the supported Servers / Browsers / Operating Systems etc.

As per the docs, the Server OS which are fully supported are

1. Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2
2. Microsoft Windows Server 2012
3. RedHat Linux Kernel 2.6 and 3.x Distributions
4. Debian Distribution incl. Ubuntu 14
5. SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12

Comment: Thanks @rackhi4110

Comment: @emdhie You are welcome. Kindly consider accepting the answer in case it helped.